# Django-registration 0.8 error: register() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

Tags: django, django-registration

I am trying to use the "simple" backend in django-registration 0.8, but my call to register yields the error "register() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)" when I go to /accounts/register (as well as at /register)

My code is below.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from registration.views import register


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home'),
    url(r'/accounts', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),    
    url(r'register', 'registration.views.register', {'success_url':''}),
)
```

Comment: Show the other side of the code that is getting called :)

Comment: That's just your `urls.py`. Show the function inside your `views.py` that is actually handling the request for `/accounts/register`

Comment: That's a call to registration.views.register from the django-registration.  It's not calling a view that I've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed the *correct* two parameters. The `register` view requires two args: `request` and `backend`. Everything else (all the kwargs) are optional. Django automatically passes `request` and you passed in the `success_url` kwarg, so that's 2, but you're missing `backend`.

Comment: Thanks.  For anyone else reading this with the same problem,  the backend for simple is registration.backends.simple.SimpleBackend -- I didn't see that in the docs, so I assumed it was somehow inferred from my include statement.  Thanks Chris!